# Linq to SQL: add a custom column and the Order By it?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How could I do something like this in Linq to SQL (VB.NET if possible)?

```
SELECT *, ISNULL(DueDate, DATEADD(year, 10, GETDATE())) AS DueDateForSorting 
FROM Tasks
ORDER BY DueDateForSorting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the SQL provider supports adding lambda columns to the query. However, it does support a coalesce operator, and since you are essentially doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks
ORDER BY ISNULL(DueDate, DATEADD(year, 10, GETDATE()))
```

Try this:

```
from o in dc.Orders orderby o.DueDate ?? DateTime.Today.AddYears(10)
```

If you need that fake, future date to also be in your resultset for some reason, you can modify the entity class in the LINQtoSQL designer.cs file:

```
[Column(Storage="_DueDate", DbType="SmallDateTime")]
public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate
{
    get
    {
        if(this._DueDate == null)
        {
            return DateTime.Today.AddYears(10);
        }
        return this._DueDate;
    }
```

So if you ever ask for DueDate on the object and DueDate is null, you'll at least get the far-future date.

Comment: How do I do the "??" in VB.net?

Comment: Ah - I got it: From o In dc.Orders Order By If(o.DueDate,DateTime.Today.AddYears(10))